# What type of mysql column to store dump?

Tags: mysql

I am aware that one can take a dump of a MySQL database in order to rollback the database at anytime. Now, I want to store this dump in a column in one of my backup tables so that I can replay that dump whenever I need to. I read the docs of the types provided by MySQL and there are two that seem to fit my need, the `text` and `blob` but am not sure which one would work best for my case here. They both seem to work out but am not sure of any caveats (if any?). I am fairly new to MySQL so any suggestions as to which one and why would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since text data type is basically a blob pre-configured to store text and your database dumps are huge text files, I would go with the text data type. Mysql documentation on [blob and text data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html) describe all similarities and differences between the 2 types in a great detail.